# Show progress Bar Untill the next activity gets loaded

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am new in android development. I have two activities in first activity there is only a button by which i am calling next activity using intent and in second activity  i am doing the actual work i.e. i am getting the values from web using SOAP.
So , My problem is that when i go from 1st activity to the second activity it shows me a BLACK screen until the next activity gets loaded totally since the response fron web is large.
I want to add a progress bar from my 1st activity to second gets loaded totally to avoid this black screen.
Do anyone have any ides about this.
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: You would better want to load your datas in the first activity, with some progress bar or spinner. when your data are ok you do you StartActivity() ;)

Comment: I didn't get actually can you give any example if you don't mind..
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four realistic solutions i would say in my opinion

**1-** Threads

**2-** Asyntask

**3-** Service

**4-** External lib

If you are doing lot of small downloads classic **Theading** is the best option maybe with a service to manage it, but not forced.

For one simple download you can use **Asynctask** alone. It can be enough but you must know several things about this method : AsyncTask can be "Bugged" according to the way you use it.

**Service** is good you can use it. A download module using service is a good idea to manage the requests.

The best solution for a quick/efficient developement is to use a library that do the work for you. But in your case you are using SOAP... If you where using Json you could make use of **Volley** which is very good and fast.

Maybe try to use this one which is well known

**http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/**

with the how to **http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse**

---

For the moment when to do the operation you have several solutions

**1-** In background without blocking the ui, updating the ui View per View

**2-** Using a loading screen (bad for user experience but sometimes you don't have a choice)

In your case you would have the loading screen between the first activity and the second using a ProgressDialog maybe